# Difference between ADO NET source and OLE DB Source in SSIS 2008?

Tags: ssis, msbi

Can anyone say the Difference between ADO NET source and OLE DB Source in SSIS 2008  ?are they both same in any context ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

With small datasets there is little difference between ADO NET source and OLE DB Source in SSIS 2008. The difference between them is how they communicate with their underlying data sources. OLEDB talks directly to OLEDB compliant sources, but ADO .NET source talks through a .NET provider.
The only reason you should use the ADO.NET source is:

- There no OLE DB providers available.
- If you need data access from within a script task.
- If you need to pass a data source to a custom component.

Comment: I might just add that parameter placeholder syntax is different when using these providers. For example ADO.NET uses @<parametername> and OLEDB uses ?. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140355.aspx

Comment: You can also use ADO.NET to bypass some of the bugs SSIS has when using temporary tables in data sources.